# get several values ​separated by , and save line by line in the database

Tags: laravel-nova

I have an input, and I want to extract several numbers separated by , and store each number on each new line in the database.

`model - CouponDocument`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Http\Controllers\CouponDocumentController;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


class CouponDocument extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "coupons_document";

    protected $fillable = [
        "id",
        "cpf",
        "coupon_id"
    ];

    protected $hidden = [

        'deleted_at',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];


    public function coupon() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Coupon::class, 'coupon_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
    }

}
```

`Controller`

```
class CouponDocumentController extends Controller
{

    static public function store($request)
    {
        $data = [];
        foreach ($request->input('cpf') as $cpf) {
            $data[] = [
                'cpf' => trim($cpf),
                'coupon_id' => 61
            ];
        }
    
        foreach ($data as $item) {

          
            $couponDocument = new CouponDocument();
            $couponDocument->fill($item);
            $couponDocument->save();
        }
    }

}
```

`Resources`

```
class CouponsDocument extends Resource
{
    use SearchesRelations;

    public static $displayInNavigation = false;

    public static $model = \App\Models\CouponDocument::class;

    public static $title = 'id';

    public static $search = [
        'id',
        'cpf',
        'coupon_id'
    ];


    public static function label()
    {
        return __('modules.couponDocument.button');
    }

    public static function singularLabel()
    {
        return __('modules.couponDocument.button');
    }

    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
          Text::make(__('fields.couponDocument.name'), "cpf")
          ->sortable(),
       
        ];
    }
```

where the resource is called

```
 HasMany::make
 __("fields.couponDocument.name"),
 "documentRelationship",
CouponsDocument::class
```

I tried to do it with the standard functions of nova, but it ended up not working, I would like to know if there is any other solution

Answer (score 0):

First i would try is to add this as a mutation in the model instead to guarante input and output is correct

```
class CouponDocument extends Model
{
    protected function cpf(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: function (string $value){
                return trim($value); // replace with logic
            } ,
            set: fn (string $value) => trim($value);; // replace with logic
    );
}

protected function coupon_id(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: function (string $value){
           return trim($value);
        } ,
        set: fn (string $value) => trim($value);,
    );
}
}
```

If you want to change value in nova resource

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
      Text::make(__('fields.couponDocument.name'), function($value){
    return $value;// insert logic 
})->sortable(),
   
    ];
```

Or when hydrating nova resource:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        Text::make(__('fields.couponDocument.name'),'cpf')
            ->fillUsing(function ($request, $model, $attribute, $requestAttribute) 
            {
                    return Str::title($request->input($attribute));
            })->sortable(),
   
    ];
 }
```